# How to remove WSL startup upgrade reminder

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I keep getting the following message whenever I start my WSL

```shell
Windows Subsystem for Linux is now available in the Microsoft Store!
You can upgrade by running 'wsl.exe --update' or by visiting https://aka.ms/wslstorepage
Installing WSL from the Microsoft Store will give you the latest WSL updates, faster.
For more information please visit https://aka.ms/wslstoreinfo
```

How do I stop getting this without having to upgrade my WSL?